# Upgraded Custom Component won't compile

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7, delphi-10.3-rio

We're currently looking at upgrading some of our Delphi applications from XE7 to 10.3 and have run into a problem with our custom components.

I've tried 2 options.

1. I've copied, opened in 10.3, and re-compiled the original component package.
2. I've created a new package in 10.3, added a copy of the relevant `.pas` files, and compiled a new `.bpl`/`.dpk` file.

In both cases, I get a package that I can install into the IDE, and which allows me to add the component into a new project.

However, in both cases, I get `"Can't resolve unit name "NewComponent""` in the IDE, and `"Unit "NewComponent" not found"` when I try and use the component in the project.

I remember this being an issue on previous Delphi updgrades, but have forgotten the trick to fix it.

Comment: For my own packages, I have a separate Lib folder (\[delphi]\Lib2, then I set the BPL Output Directory in the IDE to that folder, add it to the IDE's Search Path *and* the OS Path.  That's all and it works fine.

Comment: That's the problem. I needed to update my Library Path. Can you stick that as an answer so I can accept!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For my own packages, I have a separate Lib folder `\[delphi]\Lib2`, then I set the BPL Output Directory in the IDE to that folder, add it to the IDE's Search Path and the OS Path.

That's all I find is necessary and it works fine.

Comment: I my case I needed to add a link to the appropriate compiled folder in the Delphi setup.
I knew there was a trick in the past...